# Selenium: how to choose element from selector?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I must choose quantity of items to buy in Selenium test. I have to choose number from a list of selector. Selenium generate a following code:

```
new Select(driver.FindElement(By.Id("product-quantity-select"))).SelectByText("10");
```

But "Select" and "SelectByText" in VisualStudio are underlined. How to change code which will choose this element correctly?

Comment: Instance of what are you trying to create? You are invoking `new` and calling method `SelectByText` at the same time

Comment: I record test by SeleniumIDE in Firefox. And this code appers when I want to choose sth from selector. I want to modify this to correctly work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SelectElement se = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("product-quantity-select")));
se.SelectByText("10");
```

The class name is not `Select` but `SelectElement`. It is not possible to cast IWebElement as SelectElement, so `new SelectElement` must be used here.

Comment: Your question popped up in the Low Quality review queue. Code only answers are strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read the documentation:

The SelectElement type exposes the following members.

...

**Methods**

- Public method    SelectByIndex
  Select the option by the index, as determined by the "index" attribute of the element.
- Public method    SelectByText
  Select all options by the text displayed.
- Public method    SelectByValue
  Select an option by the value.

C# docs [here.](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/AllMembers_T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_SelectElement.htm)